# concat string arguments in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, typescript

how can I pass a concatted string via `ng-click` to MyFunction(param: string)?

I did not find any solution:

```
<input id="MeasurementValue_{{sample.Number}}_{{$index}}" 
      ng-click="Vm.MyFunction('MeasurementValue_{{sample.Number}}_{{$index}}')"/>
```

this does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```html
  <input id="MeasurementValue_{{sample.Number}}_{{$index}}"
   ng-click="Vm.MyFunction('MeasurementValue' + '_' + {{sample.Number}} + '_' + {{$index}})"
   />
```

ng-click=" you should be able to write pure JS here"

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<input id="MeasurementValue_{{sample.Number}}_{{$index}}" 
      ng-click="Vm.MyFunction('MeasurementValue_' + sample.Number + '_' + $index)"/>
```